# Downloading file in last swift version

Tags: swift, file, audio, download

Does anybody can advice the way to try about question of downloading file using swift in xcode 7.1 beta?

I tried nsdata.writetourl and few file-working-with-classes - nothing work.

I just need to download audio file, save it's way and play it in future.

Will apperciate any help storing file locally. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's this method for that:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/")!

let downloadTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(url) { url, response, error in
    print(url)
}

downloadTask.resume()
```

Comment: The question is about saving file on device and play it in future (mostly for saving file and its filename)

Comment: @SwiftStudier Yes that's what my answer's for, read online for more info on downloadTask, that's the one you need

Comment: i found nothing benefit by my question which is how to store downloaded file using latest swift version